# What's the difference between entity.put() and entity.save()?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I see in the [gae manpages](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities) that `entity.save()` is not very documented but still it can be used. What is the difference between `entity.put()` and `entity.save()`? Should `save()` never be used and only `put()` instead?

Comment: `ndb` does not define `save()`, only `put()`.  Make your future migration easier by using `put()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`save` is just a synonym for `put`. It is defined as follows in the source code:

```
save = put
```

View the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py#1074) for `save`.